# How to show the most popular articles of wordpress blog on external website?

Tags: wordpress

I have wordpress blog with "the most popular articles" widget, which is quite popular.
I have also a website based on codeigniter on wordpressblog.com/ci_site/ address.

Is there a way, to show the content given by "popular articles" widget on my codeigniter external site?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you're looking for a way to utilize an application's data in an external application, search for [`API`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) - Application Programming Interface.

In this case you would search for a [WordPress API](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_API%27s).
I tried to find a more specific API for the widged you mentioned, with no success. Most probably you will need to dig into the WordPress API and find a way to utilize it to your need.